# Select rows having 2 columns equal value in laravel Query builder

Tags: laravel

I want to write a query which selects rows where 2 attributes from 1 entity have equal value.

This would be an example of doing this in raw SQL:

```
Select * from users u where u.username = u.lastname
```

Does laravel have any methods that take 2 column names as parameters and return the matching results?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

What you need is a `DB::raw` expression:

```
DB::table('users')
    ->where('username', '=', DB::raw('lastname'))
    ->get();
```

The only thing `DB::raw` actually does is to tell the query interpreter *not* to treat `'lastname'` like any other string value but just *interpolate* it in the SQL as it is.

http://laravel.com/docs/queries#raw-expressions

Answer (score 8):

In Laravel 5, there's [now](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries) `whereColumn` for this, for cleaner code:

```
Users::whereColumn('username', 'lastname')->get();
```

Comment: this is only available since laravel 5.2, not in 5.1LTS for example. not sure why @ceejayoz rejected my edit. the answer is not accurate, since this functionality is not available "in laravel 5".

Comment: @rrrafalsz `whereColumn` is in all currently-supported versions of Laravel. 5.1's support ran out in June 2017.